# React useState async updating and for-loop

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, asynchronous, use-state

I have a seemingly elementary problem that keeps setting my projects back--useState isn't rendering correctly for me.

Here is a simplified version of the issue:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  function TestFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      setCount((curr) => curr + 1);
      console.log(count);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Count = {count}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => TestFunction()}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Upon clicking the button, the state is then set to 10, but the console.log() isn't properly updated.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging `count` before it is updated with the latest value. Simply put, when `setCount` is called, React stores the value provided to it until the next render. When the next render occurs the `count` value will be updated.

In my example below:

- The `useEffect` below will be hit every time `state` is updated.
- The `setState(curr=>curr+1)` will notify you what the current ~next~ state value is.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  // Console.log on state update
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(`useEffect: ${state}`);
  },[state]);


  function TestFunction() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      setState((curr)=>{
        console.log(`setState(nextValue): ${curr+1}`);
        return curr+1;
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Count = {state}</h3>
      <button onClick={TestFunction}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const el = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers your question

First of all you are logging count which is not yet updated for the current render. So basically `console.log` is one step behind. Check the code bellow this might clarify everything to you.

````
function Temp() {
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

function TestFunction() {
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   setCount((curr) => {
     console.log(curr);
     return curr + 1;
   });
   console.log(count);
 }
}

return (
 <>
   <h3>Count = {count}</h3>
   <button onClick={() => TestFunction()}>Click</button>
 </>
);
}

export default Temp;```
````